# forms authentication, not able to save web.config programmatically

Tags: asp.net, forms, authentication

im using visual studio 2008. in my project im using forms authentication, my project structure is as follows

```
root
 |
 login.aspx
 home.aspx
 web.config
 admin (folder)
  |
  admin.aspx
  web.config
```

here in root web.config is as follows

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name="Authen" protection="All" timeout="60" loginUrl="Login.aspx" enableCrossAppRedirects="true" cookieless="AutoDetect"/>
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

and in inner web.config

and my users are 
Username   Role
admin1      Admin
admin2      Admin
user1        User
user2        User

as you can see that in second web.config, i gave access to users with "Admin" role and "user1" user.

for giving access to "admin" folder, i wrote the following:

```
        Configuration config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~/HR");
        SystemWebSectionGroup systemWeb = (SystemWebSectionGroup)config.GetSectionGroup("system.web");
        AuthorizationSection section = (AuthorizationSection)systemWeb.Sections["authorization"];

        AuthorizationRule newRule = new AuthorizationRule(AuthorizationRuleAction.Allow);
        newRule.Users.Add("user1");
        section.Rules.Add(newRule);
```

and saved the web.config as

```
        config.Save();
```

this is working fine when i run it from visual studio development server, when i host it in IIS, im getting the following error

> Configuration Error 
>   Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: An error occurred loading a configuration file: Access to the path 'F:\dotnet\samples\myproj\UI\hr\f-q_g-yn.tmp' is denied.
>
> Source Error:
>
> [No relevant source lines]
>
> Source File: F:\dotnet\samples\myproj\UI\hr\web.config    Line: 0

here the problem is, it is not able to save the web.config

i got one solution, that is, i added

```
<identity impersonate="true" userName="myusername" password="mypassword"/>
```

to root web.config and it is working fine. but my boss says that is not the correct way. what is the correct way to solve this problem ??
please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The account your website is running under does not have permissions to write to the directory your web.config is in. There are two options how to solve that:

1. Run your website under another account which *does* have the required permissions. You set the account in the settings of the respective Application Pool in IIS Manager.
2. Modify the security settinsg (ACLs) of the directory/directories, and add write permissions for the user your application pool is running under.

You should probably combine both methods – use a separate user account and add the write permissions only to this account, not to e.g. Network Service.

(But note that I am not sure whether a website modifying its own web.config files is a good idea at all.)

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea either. When a Web.config gets modified, the application will restart. That can give some unwanted side effects.

Comment: then i have to check whether the user is authorized to access a page in a particular folder. that results into lot of coding. doesnt it. then what is the use of forms authentication ??

Comment: @Harsha - What are you trying to achieve? Enabling/disabling users’ access to various pages/folders is usually done by assigning the users to the respective _roles_, and requiring the _role_ in web.config, instead of listing all permitted users there. See e.g. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5k850zwb.aspx)

Comment: @Mormegil - you are correct, but my requirement is to allow a particular user who is in role "USR" to access pages in folder named "Manager" with role "MGR". how do i achieve this?

Comment: @Harsha - Add him (temporarily?) another role, e.g. "UPGRADEDUSR" and allow the role in the Manager folder.

Comment: @Mormegil - thats perfect. if i create another role which comes in between the two rules, that sets correctly. thanks dude.